# Python DataFrame using a small section from a large text file

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe, text

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("input.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for line in data:
        data = {'col1': [line[':']], 'col2': [line[':']], 'col3': [line[':']], 'col4': [line[':']]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print(df)
```

The problem is I keep getting back a singular row dataframe for each individual line of the text file. I need to have a full dataframe with all of the lines together. The text file itself is not formatted. So it's difficult to understand how I'm supposed to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe apprend function of pandas is what your are looking for https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a single-row dataframe because the dataframe constructor is in the loop that goes over every line of the file.

```
for line in data:
    data = ...
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

It isn't clear what your end goal is here, but I would look at the various options for `pandas.read_table`. For example, if you only want certain columns, there is a `usecols` parameter.

Another option is to do the data manipulation in pandas after you've read the file. For example, if you want a column to be a copy of a column, you can use `df['col2'] = df['col1']`

If you definitely need to loop over every line of the file, then create a list of dicts and make the dataframe at the end. You can omit `readlines` and iterate directly over `f`.

```
datadicts = []
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        datadicts.append({'col1': [line[':']], 'col2': [line[':']], 'col3': [line[':']], 'col4': [line[':']]})

df = pd.DataFrame(datadicts)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That definitely did what I needed, which was to take all the individual dataframes in each line of txt and create one big dataframe that housed all of the data.

Comment: Now, when I print my dataframe, I am getting square brackets around each of my values. Any idea how I can get rid of this?

Comment: The values for col1, col2, etc. are lists.